# What does RMSD mean?

Tags: notation, optimization, terminology, normed-spaces

Normally a rigid superposition which minimizes the RMSD is performed, and this minimum is returned. Given two sets of  points  and , the RMSD is defined as follows:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{RMSD}(\mathbf v,\mathbf w)&=\sqrt{\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\|v_i-w_i\|^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left((v_{ix}-w_{ix})^2+(v_{iy}-w_{iy})^2+(v_{iz}-w_{iz})^2\right)}
\end{align*}$$

Those descriptions are from wikipedia(bioinformatics). 
Could you explain what the equations mean?

And What does $\|\cdot\|$ mean above?

Comment: Oh, "root-mean-square difference", then?

Answer (score 2):

The `||` describes [the norm of the vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) enclosed, which is basically its length with regard to some definition.

```
|| x || = sqrt( (x_1)^2 + (x_2)^2 + ... + (x_n)^2 )
```

Where n is the amount of the dimensions of `x`.

In your case the norm is squared, which in results nullifies the `sqrt()` of the norm. In addition with working in 3 dimensions (`x`, `y` and `z`), you get to your second second line, where just the respective dimensions of each vector are used.

Just replace the `x` of the above formula with `(v_i - w_i)` and write out the norm formula squared and you will see the same result as in wikipedia.

With respect to the overall question (assuming you mean [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square_deviation_%28bioinformatics%29)):

RMSD takes two sets of points `v` and `w`, which are given as sets of vectors. Then it computes the average (hence the `1/n` in front) distance between respective pairs (thats the norm in the brackets) of all vectors of each set (hence the sum).

Comment: Oh, I now understand~ Thank you^^

Comment: Actually the square root is over the sum of squares, so it is necessary. `sqrt((2^2) + (3^2)) ~= 3.6 != 2 + 3 = 5`

Comment: @JonC I just said "nullifies the sqrt()", I didn't say anything about the squares within it.